# Java AWS Serverless Lambda

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am working with AWS serverless lambda and using Java language, while i get data from mysql inside Lambda that mysql result is actually a string which contains a list of JSON objects. But while trying to return response AWS adds slashes in response.

Response from mysql as string:

`[{"name": "ABC", "is_read_type": "1", "is_write_type": "0"}, {"name": "XYZ", "is_read_type": "1", "is_write_type": "0"} ]`

Response i get from AWS Lambda

`{"statusCode":200,"body":"[{\"is_write_type\":\"0\",\"is_read_type\":\"1\",\"name\":\"ABC\"},{\"is_write_type\":\"0\",\"is_read_type\":\"1\",\"name\":\"XYZ\"}]","headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true"},"isBase64Encoded":false}END RequestId: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx`

Here AWS is adding `\` these slashes which i do not want in response, Also I have tried parsing it using different JSON libraries including Gson and Jackson. I have also tried adding "Content-Type -> application/json" in headers but it added more slashes in response.

I want to achieve this without using POJO classes, and directly return the mysql string as JSON from AWS Lambda. Kindly help and guide.

P.S. I am new to Java

Comment: Is there some api gateway in between or are you directly invoking the lambda? The `body` is simply a json string again, decode it e.g. with gson or some other library: decode the entire response and then decode the `body` again.

Comment: @luk2303 i am using AWS API Gateway for calling AWS lambda

Comment: AWS uses JSON for its payload (the wrapper, which includes status code, etc.), and your payload is also JSON. So the only sensible choice is for them to escape your JSON and insert it as a string. Your JSON could be mangled, not have the right amount of braces etc. By escaping your JSON, they ensure that the wrapper JSON is not broken because of any bugs in your code which generates the payload. So you cannot turn it off. It is designed this way. It should be trivial to unescape it, see the linked duplicate

Comment: @Michael Sure i am going to try the linked duplicate,

Comment: @Michael I want to add one thing here. the response i am getting from mysql and printing in console is completely fine, the issue only happens then AWS lambda returns this in response so technically how can i unescape it ? if i have the completely okay string before AWS API Gateway processes it.